# function vbavarindexload in msvbvm60.dll, what is doing ? and Parameters?

Tags: ollydbg, x64dbg

I need urgent help , I was debugging a software made by Visual basic 6 , and I found
vbavarindexload  function and I need to know what is doing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. So, what have you found out as of yet?

Answer (score 1):

Did you miss the two underscores in this function? Most Google results show that it should be `__vbaVarIndexLoad`.

If so, it is a function reserved for internal use and you shouldn't care too much about it. Judging by its name it probably pushes a variable on the VM stack by the index.

While working with Visual basic programs, you should check if it is p-code compiled or native code compiled, then choose correct tools, since usually you don't want to reverse the whole VM.